# failed to attach to these type of code Manager(4.0), Process W3p.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Unable to attach worker process, this is 32 bit machine, and iis 7.5 and using .net framework 4.0.

the app pool is configured to use 4.0 framework

Comment: error msg : Successfull added these type ode code :T-SQL Failed to add these type of code  Managed (4.0)

Comment: this is an urgent issue to be fixed in my project, however unable to find the root cause and unable to debug my application